# Json Parse invalid character

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to read a Json object that was serialized by JavaScriptSerializer Serialize .NET function. But I am getting invalid character error in JSON.parse. What am I missing?

This is the Json String generated by the function:

```
[
    {
        "Word":"areopagus",
        "Definition":"Def 1",
        "Rank":1
    },
    {
        "Word":"areopagus",
        "Definition":"Def 2",
        "Rank":2
    }
]
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetWordDefinition(string word)
{
    List<vwWordDefinition> w = db.vwWordDefinitions.Where(x => x.Word == word).OrderBy(x => x.Rank).ToList();
    var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(w);
    return new ContentResult { Content = json, ContentType = "application/json" };
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $('#btnViewDefinition').click(function () {       
        if ($('#searchString').val() != null) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetWordDefinition", "WordList")',
                cache: false,
                data: { word: $('#searchString').val() },
                datatype: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (result) {

                    var jsonData = JSON.parse(result);
                    for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
                        var w = jsonData[i];
                        console.log(w.Word);
                        console.log(w.Definition);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `datatype: 'json'` instructs `$.ajax()` to parse the response. `result` should already be an Array of Objects.

Comment: to expand, you're trying to parse '[objectObject]' since jq already parsed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`datatype: 'json'` instructs `$.ajax()` to parse the response. The `result` will already be an array of objects and **not** a JSON string. Your subsequent attempt to parse the array as a string is causing the error.

From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object

*Note: This answer was cobbled together from the comments so I have marked it Community Wiki.*